# Create a Composite Primary Key in the junction table with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Please see the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist;

namespace NHibernateCodeMapping
{
    public class Person
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Sport> sports { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            sports = new List<Sport>();
        }
    }

    public class Sport
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Person> people { get; set; }

        public Sport()
        {
            people = new List<Person>();
        }
    }

    public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            Id<Guid>(x => x.Id);
            Property<string>(x => x.Name);

            Bag(x => x.sports, collectionMapping =>
            {
                collectionMapping.Table("PersonSports");
                collectionMapping.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                collectionMapping.Key(keyMapper => keyMapper.Column("PersonId"));
                //collectionMapping.Key(k => k.Column("SportId"));
            },
            map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("SportId")));
        }
    }

    public class SportMap : ClassMapping<Sport>
    {
        public SportMap()
        {
            Id<Guid>(x => x.Id);
            Property<string>(x => x.Description);
            Bag(x => x.people, collectionMapping =>
            {
                collectionMapping.Table("PersonSports");
                collectionMapping.Key(keyMapper => keyMapper.Column("SportId"));
                collectionMapping.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                //collectionMapping.Key(k => k.Column("PersonId"));
            },
            map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("PersonId")));
        }
    }
}
```

It works as I would expect i.e. three tables are created: Person; Sport and PersonSport.  PersonSport is the junction table to support the many to many relationship between Person and Sport.

How do I create a composite Primary Key on the PersonSport table (Personid, SportId)? Please see the two lines that are commented out, which shows what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected if I add the following classes:

```
public class SportMap : ClassMapping<Sport>
    {
        public SportMap()
        {
            Id<Guid>(x => x.Id);
            Property<string>(x => x.Description);
            Bag(x => x.people, collectionMapping =>
            {
                collectionMapping.Table("PersonSports");
                //collectionMapping.Key(keyMapper => keyMapper.Column("SportId"));
                collectionMapping.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                collectionMapping.Key(k => k.Column("PersonId"));
            },
            map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("SportId")));
        }
    }

    public class PersonSports
    {
        public virtual Guid SportId { get; set; }
        public virtual Guid PersonId { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class PersonSportsMap : ClassMapping<PersonSports>
    {
        public PersonSportsMap()
        {
            ComposedId(map =>
            {
                map.Property(x => x.PersonId);
                map.Property(x => x.SportId);
            });
        }
    }
```

Therefore I have to:

1) Create the collections in the classes (Person.Sports and Sports.Person) meaning there are effectively two one to many relationships.

and

2) Create the junction table explicitly

I am not sure if this is normal practice (to do both of the above) and would be grateful for some comments.